# SCSS in Cloud Pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, css, cloudpage, landing-page

I am trying to copy a new landing page but it uses an SCSS instead of just plain CSS.

Does SFMC support Sassy Cascading Style Sheets (SCSS)?
If yes, how can I make this work?